# How to make only flex item overflow and not whole parent?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a small basic layout page.

Content in the center with a sidebar that contains filters.

Please see: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ePLmKB?editors=1100

I would like my `.heading` and `.filter-block-heading` to always be visible and only have the actual filter cards be scrollable. The issue is the whole flex column overflows making my column header scroll out of view

I need the content in the .main section to be able to extend the whole .content section. If the content is small, max height is the viewport minus the footer height. But if the content extends, the sidebars should extend too.

I've tried setting `overflow: hidden` on parents and then `overflow: auto` on the child.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 1024px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

header {
  background-color: #b4d15e;
}

footer {
  height: 56px;
  background-color: #5ed1b4;
}

.content {
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 56px);
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(20% + 0px);
  max-width: 300px;
  min-width: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4.9px 0.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-color: #e0e1e6;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 1px 0 0;
  flex: none;
  background: #f4f5f8;
}

.heading {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.heading h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.heading>div {
  display: flex;
  padding: 15px 7px 15px 12px;
  align-items: center;
}

.filters {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.filter-block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.filter-block-heading {
  min-height: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-bottom: solid 3px #404c9a;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.single-filters {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%
}

.filter-card {
  width: 100% padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  border-bottom: 2px solid green;
}

.filter-card h3 {
  background-color: #A8AAFF;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.filter-card li {
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  width: 580px;
  padding: 30px;
}

.sidebar-2 {
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.25s;
  width: calc(25% + 30px);
  max-width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4.9px 0.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='app'>
    <header>
      Header</header>
    <div class='content'>

      <div class='sidebar-1'>
        <div class='heading'>
          <div>
            <h2>All Filters</h2>
            <button>Show all</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class='filters'>
          <div>

            <div class='filter-block'>
              <div class='filter-block-heading'>
                Custom Filters
              </div>

              <div class='single-filters'>

                <div>

                  <div class='filter-card'>
                    <h3>Single Filter</h3>
                    <ul>
                      <li>Option 1</li>
                      <li>Option 2</li>
                      <li>Option 3</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class='filter-card'>
                    <h3>Single Filter</h3>
                    <ul>
                      <li>Option 1</li>
                      <li>Option 2</li>
                      <li>Option 3</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class='filter-card'>
                    <h3>Single Filter</h3>
                    <ul>
                      <li>Option 1</li>
                      <li>Option 2</li>
                      <li>Option 3</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class='filter-card'>
                    <h3>Single Filter</h3>
                    <ul>
                      <li>Option 1</li>
                      <li>Option 2</li>
                      <li>Option 3</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class='filter-card'>
                    <h3>Single Filter</h3>
                    <ul>
                      <li>Option 1</li>
                      <li>Option 2</li>
                      <li>Option 3</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class='filter-card'>
                    <h3>Single Filter</h3>
                    <ul>
                      <li>Option 1</li>
                      <li>Option 2</li>
                      <li>Option 3</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class='filter-card'>
                    <h3>Single Filter</h3>
                    <ul>
                      <li>Option 1</li>
                      <li>Option 2</li>
                      <li>Option 3</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class='filter-card'>
                    <h3>Single Filter</h3>
                    <ul>
                      <li>Option 1</li>
                      <li>Option 2</li>
                      <li>Option 3</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class='filter-card'>
                    <h3>Single Filter</h3>
                    <ul>
                      <li>Option 1</li>
                      <li>Option 2</li>
                      <li>Option 3</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class='filter-card'>
                    <h3>Single Filter</h3>
                    <ul>
                      <li>Option 1</li>
                      <li>Option 2</li>
                      <li>Option 3</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='main'>main</div>
      <div class='sidebar-2'>sidebar 2</div>
    </div>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: take the sidebar outside the content and have the content `overflow:auto` and add `overflow:hidden` to the body

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're getting a scrollbar on the viewport because of this rule:

```
.content {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 56px);
}
```

So you're removing 56px from the height, which is the height of the `footer`:

```
footer {
    height: 56px;
}
```

But you didn't subtract the height of the `header`. That's why there's an overflow.

Try this instead:

[revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qJMRoO?editors=1100)

```css
/* body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
} */

.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 1024px;
  width: 100%;
  /* height: auto; */
  height: 100vh; /* new */  
}

.content {
  flex-direction: row;
  /* min-height: calc(100vh - 56px); */
  flex: 1; /* new */
  display: flex;
}

/* no more changes */

header {
  background-color: #b4d15e;
}

footer {
  height: 56px;
  background-color: #5ed1b4;
}


.sidebar-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(20% + 0px);
  max-width: 300px;
  min-width: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4.9px 0.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-color: #e0e1e6;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 1px 0 0;
  flex: none;
  background: #f4f5f8;
}

.heading {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.heading  h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.heading > div {
  display: flex;
  padding: 15px 7px 15px 12px;
  align-items: center;
}

.filters {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.filter-block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.filter-block-heading {
  min-height: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-bottom: solid 3px #404c9a;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.single-filters {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%
}

.filter-card {
  width: 100%
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  border-bottom: 2px solid green;
}

.filter-card h3 {
  background-color: #A8AAFF;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.filter-card li {
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  width: 580px;
  padding: 30px;
}

.sidebar-2 {
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.25s;
  width: calc(25% + 30px);
  max-width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4.9px 0.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='app'>
    <header>Header</header>
    <div class='content'>
      <div class='sidebar-1'>
        <div class='heading'>
          <div>
            <h2>All Filters</h2>
            <button>Show all</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='filters'>
          <div>
            <div class='filter-block'>
              <div class='filter-block-heading'>
                Custom Filters
              </div>
              <div class='single-filters'>
                <div>
                  <div class='filter-card'>
                    <h3>Single Filter</h3>
                    <ul>
                      <li>Option 1</li>
                      <li>Option 2</li>
                      <li>Option 3</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class='filter-card'>
                    <h3>Single Filter</h3>
                    <ul>
                      <li>Option 1</li>
                      <li>Option 2</li>
                      <li>Option 3</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class='filter-card'>
                    <h3>Single Filter</h3>
                    <ul>
                      <li>Option 1</li>
                      <li>Option 2</li>
                      <li>Option 3</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class='filter-card'>
                    <h3>Single Filter</h3>
                    <ul>
                      <li>Option 1</li>
                      <li>Option 2</li>
                      <li>Option 3</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class='filter-card'>
                    <h3>Single Filter</h3>
                    <ul>
                      <li>Option 1</li>
                      <li>Option 2</li>
                      <li>Option 3</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class='filter-card'>
                    <h3>Single Filter</h3>
                    <ul>
                      <li>Option 1</li>
                      <li>Option 2</li>
                      <li>Option 3</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class='filter-card'>
                    <h3>Single Filter</h3>
                    <ul>
                      <li>Option 1</li>
                      <li>Option 2</li>
                      <li>Option 3</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class='filter-card'>
                    <h3>Single Filter</h3>
                    <ul>
                      <li>Option 1</li>
                      <li>Option 2</li>
                      <li>Option 3</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class='filter-card'>
                    <h3>Single Filter</h3>
                    <ul>
                      <li>Option 1</li>
                      <li>Option 2</li>
                      <li>Option 3</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class='filter-card'>
                    <h3>Single Filter</h3>
                    <ul>
                      <li>Option 1</li>
                      <li>Option 2</li>
                      <li>Option 3</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='main'>main</div>
      <div class='sidebar-2'>sidebar 2</div>
    </div>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The scrollbar isn't the issue. It's scrolling the wrong content. There could 70 filters for example, so the individual filters card only need to be scrolled

Comment: I didn't read the question carefully enough the first time around. My bad. How's this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pxOPvE?editors=1100

Comment: Keep in mind that for the `overflow` property to work reliably across browsers, there needs to be an actual overflow of a fixed length. Hence, I've added some fixed heights to headings to ensure that it works. It won't work on all browsers using just flexible lengths.

Comment: very very close. One point I forgot to mention.
I need the content in the `.main` section to be able to extend the whole `.content` section. 

If the content is small, max height is the viewport minus the footer height. But if the content extends, the sidebars should extend too.